# Java: If condition is false and still executes

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I've tried looking but didn't find an answer anywhere, and I don't see where is the problem.

When executing the program, the value of `calc!=odd` is false, and I've even made the console print it's value to make sure, and right after, the if statement executes and returns false to main

Did the same thing with `calc!=even` with a different size matrix

I really don't know what is the problem, hope someone can clarify, thanks.

```
public class snake {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[5][7];
        putNumbers(matrix);
        printMatrix(matrix);
        System.out.println("the matrix is snake? " + isSnake(matrix, matrix.length));
    }

    private static Boolean isSnake(int[][] matrix, int length) {
        length--;
        int calc,
        odd = -1,
        even = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (matrix[length].length - 2); i++) {
            calc = matrix[length][i] - matrix[length][i + 1];
            if (length % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(calc != odd); //value is false - prints
                if (calc != odd); //executes anyway even when false
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                   System.out.println(calc != even);
                   if (calc != even); {
                      return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (length == 0) return true;
        return isSnake(matrix, length - 1);
    }

    private static void putNumbers(int[][] matrix) {
        int n = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++, n++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = n;
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = matrix[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--, n++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = n;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            System.out.printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 if(length%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println(calc!=odd);  //value is false - prints
            if (calc!=odd);                 // <<-- NOTE THE SEMICOLON
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the Findbugs plugin to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: wow, i feel dumb even asking it now, thank you

Comment: Dang it! How could it even be the mistake in first place :DD. Lol

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra semi colon after the if condition, just remove it

```
if (calc!=odd);
```